# Angular - How to correctly use Services, HttpClient and Observables to pass an array of objects around my application

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, httpclient

I've been really struggling to understand this and lots of the examples talk about Observables or HttpClient but not both together (at least not how i'm thinking).

I have a collection of Categories that come from the database.  These categories have a few properties and are used in several different components in my application.

```
export class Category {
    public Id: string = null;
    public Name: string = null;
    public Order: number = null;
}
```

I have an angular service that calls the back end to get me the list of Categories.  Some of the components have functions that create new categories. 
In this instance, I would like all subscribers, to the initial list, to be updated with the new category.

```
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }

  public getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Category[]>('/api/CategoryAdmin/GetCategories');
  }

  public addCategory(newCategory: Category) {
    this.httpClient.post('/api/CategoryAdmin/AddCategory', newCategory).subscribe((result: Category) => {
      // what to do here?
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

}
```

In the above example, I can't see how I would make it so initial subscribers to getCategories() would receive the new category that's been added.  I think i need to store the array of categories in the CategoryService, and then have each subscriber subscribe to that. However, i'm struggling to understand how to do that correctly. I looked into subjects, and i think that might be the way to do it but again the method to do it was escaping me.

Would anyone be so kind as to provide an example or point me in the right direction?

---

Update: Based on the answers below I ended up updating my code to the following. I've pasted the whole thing as i figured it might help people understand better.

```
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }
  private _categories = new BehaviorSubject<CommandCategory[]>([]);
  private categories: CommandCategory[] = [];
  private loading: boolean = false;

  public get(): Observable<CommandCategory[]> {
    this.load();
    return this._categories.asObservable();
  }

  public load() {
    if (this.categories.length === 0 && !this.loading) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.httpClient.get<CommandCategory[]>('/api/CategoryAdmin/GetCategories').subscribe((data: CommandCategory[]) => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.categories = data;
          this._categories.next(this.categories);
        },
        error => {
          this.loading = false;
          console.log('Could not load categories.');
        });
    }
  }


  public save(categories: CommandCategory[]) {
    this.httpClient.post('/api/CategoryAdmin/SaveCategories', categories).subscribe(() => {
      for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        if (categories[i].IsDeleted)
          categories.splice(i, 1);
      }
      this.categories = categories;
      this._categories.next(this.categories);
    }, error => console.log('Could not save categories.'));
  }


  public add(category: CommandCategory) {
    this.httpClient.post('/api/CategoryAdmin/AddCategory', category).subscribe((result: CommandCategory) => {
      this.categories.push(result);
      this._categories.next(this.categories);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your methods deal with the API's response in different places:

- `getCategories()` simply passes on the list of retrieved categories to the component/service which requested them.
- `addCategory()` is subscribed in the actual `CategoryService`

So you're dealing with data-storage in two different places:

You either hold the list of categories in the service and the components use it (therefore your `addCategory()` method could just push the newly created category to the existing list)

Or you do as in `getCategories()` and return the newly created category back to the entity which added it (supposing it's the one holding the complete list of categories).

---

**Edit**: Based on your comment I've done a quick [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u52pyv) with a possible solution to your problem. It basically subscribes through the `async` pipe to a SPOT located in the `service`.

Comment: Thanks. That's my example being poor.  If i was to adjust the getCategories method to store the array in the service. How would i then give the opportunity for other components to subscribe to that array?  A simple array wouldnt be enough to do that. Presumably i would make it an Observable of some sort and then push categories into it as i need to.  Also, how do you handle the initial loading and subsequent subscriptions to that array?  For example, first time round, calling the backend would be obvious, but when a second component subscribes, you wouldnt want to call the back end again?

Comment: Oh, now i feel rather stupid. I have to hold an array of the original objects and an observable array that ties with it.   Makes a lot of sense now i see it in front of me. Thank you

Comment: @JSG_85 @Piercy The solution proposed in the stackblitz example where an Observable is created from an array using `of` isn't ideal and rather hacky. It only works because of Angulars change detection mechanism when using the `async pipe` and `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`. It doesn't work when you subscribe in the component or when you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. It's generall better to work with Subjects in those cases.

Comment: @fridoo I actually ended up using subjects. I just needed the kick in the right direction to use an additional array as well as the observable / subject object. I've updated my question to show the entire solution i ended up on